# Angular : How declare variable at Module and access it from all component?

Tags: angular

I want to declare variable in my app.module and access it from children components
without declare it again or use global injection.

Is this possible?

Comment: You should use services for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a `String Token` and inject it at your component via `Injector` from `@angular/core`.

App.module.ts

```
const testVar = 'some value';
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    { provide: 'A', useValue: testVar}   // define a string token
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Component

```
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private injector: Injector) {
  const A = this.injector.get('A');
  console.log(A);
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5c6huk?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts)